# I can not convert my lists to tensors for fit in keras model

Tags: python

i defined a deep model like below:

```
    model = Sequential()
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(19,))
    layer1 = Dense(38, activation='relu')(inputs)
    layer2 = Dense(19, activation='relu')(layer1)
    layer3 = Dense(38, activation='relu')(layer2)

    outputs1 = keras.layers.Dense(19, activation='softmax', name='loss1')(layer3)
    outputs2 = keras.layers.Dense(19, activation='softmax', name='loss2')(layer3)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs1,outputs2])

   model.compile(loss=['kullback_leibler_divergence', 'kullback_leibler_divergence'], 
   metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam', loss_weights=[1.0, 1.0])

   model.fit(X_train,[y1_target,y2_target],epochs=10,batch_size=64)
```

but I get this error:

Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).

so i've tried to convert list to tensor by:

```
    tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train, dtype=tf.float32)
```

i've got this error: setting an array element with a sequence.

so I tried to use the below code:

```
    def vector_seq(sequences, dimension =19):
      print(type(sequences))
      results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
      for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
         results[i, sequence] = 1.
    return results

    X_train = vector_seq(X_train)
   y1_target = asarray(y1_target)
   y2_target = asarray(y2_target)
```

but again for the above code I've got this error:
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

X_train is like this image: [image]
and y1_target and y2_target are similar to X_train.

How can I solve these errors?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, first convert X_train to numpy array (initiall X_train was rows of dataframe (one column) :

```
    X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
```

then

```
    X = np.array(X_train.tolist())

    X=tf.convert_to_tensor(X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

and it works!